# Convert Odds Ratio to Raw Number for Meta-Analysis (using r)

Tags: r, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I am conducting a meta-analysis. Most of the studies reported raw numbers for each group, but some reported only odds ratio with confidence interval. Is there a way in r that I can back-calculate odds ratio to raw number?

If not, is there a way to use odds ratio with confidence interval for all studies to do a meta-analysis in r?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would be far better to go the other way. Compute the odds ratio from the raw numbers. It is perfectly possible to do all of this including conversion and subsequent analysis in R. The two most used packages are metafor and meta, both available from CRAN.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I have seen rma(yi, vi, data) as the most common used r-code, but if I only have odds ratio with 95% CI, how can I convert that to the "yi" and "vi"?

Comment: If you are computing the odds ratio from the raw numbers investigate the escalc() function in metafor. Note you need the log(OR) and its se not the OR. You can backcalculate this from the OR and Ci by taking logs of all three values and working back to the se.

Comment: Incidentally you need the sei parameter if you have the se. Or square it to get the sampling variance.

Comment: Check this paper: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26053541/ The formulas are very easily implemented in R.